# Adding similar jQuery behavior to a range of elements

Tags: jquery

I have added the following behavior to a range of divs.

```
$("div#_FIRST_Menu").click(function () {
  ...
  $("div#_FIRST_Content").toggleClass("property1 property2");
});

$("div#_SECOND_Menu").click(function () {
  ...
  $("div#_SECOND_Content").toggleClass("property1 property2");
});
```

Now that the solution works as supposed to i can unleash my passion for code hygiene. The immediate question, the answer to which i can't really see is how to go about {see title here}. I'd like to perform something along the lines of this.

```
$("div#_" + MAGIC_MARKER + "_Menu").click(function () {
  ...
  $("div#" + MAGIC_MARKER+ "Content").toggleClass("property1 property2");
});
```

That way i would be able to neatly compact the code, still keeping it readable. Suggestions?

Comment: What does your markup look like? You might be able to use traversal functions.

Comment: It's just a bunch of divs, showing and hiding.

Comment: Yes, that can be deduced from your JavaScript. However, in HTML, how are they related to each other? For example, are `content` divs placed next to `menu` divs? Or are they children of them?

Comment: Ah, sorry. No, they are in different divs, menu by itself and the contents by itself. No mark-up'ish connecction at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, instead of:

```
$("div#_FIRST_Menu")
```

use simply:

```
$("#_FIRST_Menu")
```

It's simpler and faster.

Now, the correct way to do it would be to add a class to all of those divs that you want to select. For example if you have:

```
<div id="_FIRST_Menu" class=menu> ... </div>
<div id="_FIRST_Content" class=content> ... </div>
<div id="_SECOND_Menu" class=menu> ... </div>
<div id="_SECOND_Content" class=content> ... </div>
```

then you can just use this:

```
$("div.menu").click(function () {
    ...
});
```

and inside that function you can use for example:

```
    $(this).next().toggleClass("property1 property2");
```

to get the next sibling, or some other function to find the correct element. You didn't show your HTML so I don't know how it exactly looks like.

Comment: There it was. I tried that but i had forgotten to reference jQuery object so it was "this.toggleClass(...). Now i got it working. Also, the "div#uniqueId" was for emphasizing that it's a div we're talking about but it's still a valid and good point. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
$.each( ["FIRST","SECOND","THIRD","ETC..."], function(i,MAGIC_MARKER){
    $("div#_" + MAGIC_MARKER + "_Menu").click(function () {
         ...
        $("div#" + MAGIC_MARKER+ "Content").toggleClass("property1 property2");
    });         
});
```

Alternatively, instead of using `"#_" + MAGIC_MARKER + "_Menu"` and `"#" + MAGIC_MARKER+ "Content"` ids, you can use classes in this way:

```
$("div.class-for-magic-markers-menu").data('index',function(i){  return i; })
                                     .click(function(){
     $("div.class-for-magic-markers-content").eq($(this).data('index'))
                                             .toggleClass("property1 property2");
});
```

Comment: I'll try out this one. It's better than the current. However, wouldn't it be even neater not to mention "FIRST", "SECOND" etc. Just to select ALL elements satisfying the criteria "abcd" + VARIABLE + "efgh" and then add to each behavior like ".addClass("xxx" + VARIABLE). Is it doable via some kind of regex?

Comment: @KonradViltersten I have updated my answer, that could be helpfull.

Answer (score 1):

its universal code

```
$("div").click(function () {
  var id = $(this).attr('id');

  var pairs = id.split('_');

  if ( pairs[2] == 'Menu'){
   var marker = 'div#_'+pairs[1]+'_Content';
   $(marker).toggleClass("property1 property2");      
  }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
$("div#_FIRST_Menu, div #_SECOND_Menu").click(function () {
...
    $("div#_FIRST_Content, div#_SECOND_Content").toggleClass("property1 property2");
});
```

Comment: This will toggle all if any is clicked.

Comment: Besides that, it would be a killer to list all the menus. I'm trying to each'em all in one shot.